ActiveMQ Artemis Kubernetes operator + federation
I am trying to setup two different instances of ActiveMQ Artemis CRD with Kubernetes; the two are supposed to talk via federation (for specific topics), so that a message sent over to instance 1 is propagated to instance 2. Federation (with a geographical partitioning of user base) is a requirement of my use case. Clustering inside every federated node is needed for high availability.
Federation configuration does not seem to be exposed via operator properties. The only way is overriding broker.xml via a custom init container or setting a list of values in brokerProperties operator property, which is a bit involved. Anyway, that is just a bit inconvenient.
The question is: I am not sure of the correct configuration of ports and services for federation, to avoid conflicting with internal communication inside the Artemis instance (pod + services).
I have tried opening a custom acceptor and a custom k8s service to expose the federation connection, but when upstream federation is configured and a message is received, the pod logs a failure trying to contact the other instance, without much detail.
Notice that the remote hostname is correctly looked for and resolved.
2024-10-03 12:40:47,842 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl] Trying reconnection attempt 0/1
2024-10-03 12:40:47,842 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl] Trying to connect with connectorFactory=org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory@3b367fd6 and currentConnectorConfig: TransportConfiguration(name=connCore, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory)?port=61617&host=test-artemis-its-broker-core-svc
2024-10-03 12:40:47,842 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector] Connector NettyConnector [host=test-artemis-its-broker-core-svc, port=61617, httpEnabled=false, httpUpgradeEnabled=false, useServlet=false, servletPath=/messaging/ActiveMQServlet, sslEnabled=false, useNio=true] using native epoll
2024-10-03 12:40:47,842 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector] Started EPOLL Netty Connector version 4.1.109.Final to test-artemis-its-broker-core-svc:61617
2024-10-03 12:40:47,842 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector] Remote destination: test-artemis-its-broker-core-svc/10.98.141.87:61617
2024-10-03 12:40:47,842 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector] Added ActiveMQClientChannelHandler to Channel with id = 1f7b3860 
2024-10-03 12:40:47,842 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl] Connector towards NettyConnector [host=test-artemis-its-broker-core-svc, port=61617, httpEnabled=false, httpUpgradeEnabled=false, useServlet=false, servletPath=/messaging/ActiveMQServlet, sslEnabled=false, useNio=true] failed
2024-10-03 12:40:47,842 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl] no connection been made, returning null


Apache ActiveMQ Artemis supports federation over CORE and AMQP protocols. Both federations can be configured by using the broker properties, see testFederationUpstreamConfiguration for the CORE protocol and testAMQPFederationRemoteAddressPolicyConfiguration for the AMQP protocol.
The broker properties can be defined in the field spec.brokerProperties of the ActiveMQArtemis CRD.
The ArtemisCloud Operator Work Queue test sets up an AMQP federation by using the StefuleSet Stable Network ID of the broker pods
